# Access to http://localhost:65418/api/stripe has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-2.1, visual-studio-2019

I set up my CORS policy in net core as shown below:

```
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", corsBuilder =>
    {
       corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials();
    }));
```

and:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc();
```

I am getting a CORS blocked error on the angular front end. When I cut/paste the link in chrome dev window it resolves to the correct url.  I have looked at many other CORS questions on stackoveflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, Change

```
app.UseCors();
```

to

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```